# Jquery Dialog Redirection Issue

Tags: jquery, redirect, dialog

I am using Jquery dialog box(jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js). The source for this dialog box is an aspx(src.aspx) page containing a html textbox.  When I press "Enter" in the html textbox, it redirects the page to the dialog page source page i.e. src.aspx (the complete content of the dialog box is displayed in the browser not as dialog box content but as an aspx page). So, tell me a way to stop/block this redirection.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So you made a complete page for 1 html textbox? How about instead taking that dialog onto your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you have a submit button on your aspx page? if so then that is your issue and it happens by default with your form.
See: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx
or use javascript to prevent the submit on enter.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1355662/2780799.aspx

Comment: No, I don't have any submit button on aspx page.